# How can I define the run order of vagrant middleware plugins?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, rhel, vagrant-plugin

I'm creating a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 VM in VirtualBox with vagrant. If I have a base box that both doesn't have the VirtualBox guest additions, and isn't registered, then I'd manually need to do the following:

- Register the box with subscription-manager
- Install guest additions

The reason that I'd need to perform registration first, is that to install guest additions, I'd need to install some extra packages.

Now, there are 3rd-party vagrant plugins for both of these tasks: [vagrant-registration](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/vagrant-registration/) and [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest).

The issue that I'm having is that the `vagrant-vbguest` plugin will always try to run first, and will fail to download the packages that it needs, because the `vagrant-registration` plugin hasn't yet had a chance to register the system.

Is there a way to force one of them to be run before the other? Or any other alternative solution that I haven't thought of yet (I'm not a vagrant wizard (or is that just called a vagrant?) yet)?

Comment: might not be the answer you're looking for but you can disable the vbguest plugin for your vm (adding `config.vbguest.auto_update = false` ) and run it manually after its launched with `vagrant vbguest`.

Comment: @FredericHenri Yes, I had figured that out, thanks. What I'm looking for is a better way. Thanks for commenting anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the spirit of my comments but it should be in a more automatic way

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-registration")
    system "vagrant vbguest --auto-reboot --no-provision" if ARGV[0] == 'up'
  end
```

not sure though that it will run in the correct order (did not try myself)

**Edit** the issue with this code is that it will try to run the vbguest right when the command is launched so before the vm is running so vbguest cannot install the necessary libs.

the other possibility I see is to use the vagrant trigger plugin (https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers), you can define to run specific script after specific command has been run

```
config.vbguest.auto_update = false
config.trigger.after :up do
  run "vagrant vbguest --auto-reboot --no-provision"
end
```

the vbguest is correctly run after the machine is booted (so I am assuming after vagrant-registration did its own stuff)

the output (interesting part) of running `vagrant up` :

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/precise
==> default: Running triggers after up...
==> default: Executing command "vagrant vbguest --auto-reboot --no-provision"...
==> default: GuestAdditions versions on your host (4.3.16) and guest (4.2.0) do not match.
```

installation of the guest additions goes on and machine rebooted ok

Comment: Thanks for your input. It seems like vagrant doesn't like being run with exec though. Here's what I get (even if I change it to `vagrant status`): "Vagrant appears to be running in a Bundler environment. Your 
existing Gemfile will be used. Vagrant will not auto-load any plugins
installed with `vagrant plugin`. Vagrant will autoload any plugins in
the 'plugins' group in your Gemfile. You can force Vagrant to take over
with VAGRANT_FORCE_BUNDLER." This seems to then loop infinitely.

Comment: did you try replacing `exec`by `system` ?

Comment: I just tried that now, and it killed my host machine with vagrant processes. Is there a way to 'exec' or 'system' just for particular vagrant commands? I think the issue is that it's running even if i say `vagrant status`

Comment: there is way to run only for particular command but it does not work, it does not wait to run. editing by using the vagrant trigger plugin -

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an issue with vagrant-registration plugin. See https://github.com/projectatomic/adb-vagrant-registration/issues/69

The issue has been fixed and the fixed version is released now i.e. https://rubygems.org/gems/vagrant-registration/versions/1.2.2